# Excel macro loop and append

Tags: vba, excel

I'm relatively new to coding, but have worked in VBA before (many moons ago...)

When the User presses the button and activates the macro, an InputBox appears and asks for the Player Name, then, asks for the number of lottery tickets that were bought by the player, and then randomizes three numbers from 1-24 (That appear in ascending order and do not repeat, much like our lotto, I still have not been able to code this condition; I'll get there later...)

After the initial code runs, it inputs all the data rows 2 through the number of tickets + 1, this all works so far; however, I would like to be able to append to the current list every time the macro is run (every button press). I have tried a couple different ways of doing this, with no success. Please help. What am I doing wrong?

```
Sub New_Entry()
    Dim strPlayer As String, strTick As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer

    strPlayer = InputBox("Input Player Name")
    strTick = InputBox("How many tickets?")

'   For i = 2 To strTick + 1 <-- This works for a single loop that does not append to the previous data
'   For i = Range(i & Range(i & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) To Range(i & Range(i & Rows.Count).End(xlUp) + strTick) <-- This does not work, at all.

        For j = 1 To 4
            Cells(i, 1).Value = strPlayer
            Cells(i, j).Value = Int((24 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub

'    Range("A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = strPlayer
'    Range("B" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = i
'    Range("C" & Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = j
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `j` goes from 1 to 4, it would overwrite the player name (while having it in the second loop, the player will also be printed 4 times)... firstly, `j` only should go from 2 to 4... secondly `Cells(i, 1).Value = strPlayer` should be outside the second loop... and third: you already got the appending part.
Just merging everything together you already have, I get this:

```
Sub New_Entry()
  Dim strPlayer As String, strTick As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer
  strPlayer = InputBox("Input Player Name")
  strTick = InputBox("How many tickets?")
  i = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
  For i = i To i + strTick - 1
    Cells(i, 1).Value = strPlayer
    For j = 2 To 4
      Cells(i, j).Value = Int((24 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
    Next j
  Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

Doesn't look wrong in the first place... just the rnd-part needs to be improved. Still, that wasnt part of the question ;)

**EDIT**
For the "no-repeat" i suggest using a collection like this:

```
Sub New_Entry()
  Dim strPlayer As String, strTick As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer
  Dim ColA As New Collection
  strPlayer = InputBox("Input Player Name")
  strTick = InputBox("How many tickets?")
  i = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
  For i = i To i + strTick - 1
    Cells(i, 1).Value = strPlayer
    For j = 1 To 24
      ColA.Add j
    Next
    While ColA.Count > 3
      ColA.Remove Int(ColA.Count * Rnd + 1)
    Wend
    For j = 2 To 4
      Cells(i, j).Value = ColA(1)
      ColA.Remove 1
    Next j
  Next i
End Sub
```

If you still have any questions, just ask :)

Comment: @JacobHooper ...added the unique-sorted-numbers part ;)